# How to set programatically the button size to fullscreen in android studio?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraintlayout and I want to build a ButtonImage that when I run the app, its size become fullscreen.
I know I can make this with
`android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent"` 
from xml, but if I want to move the ButtonImage it creates a wide laggy image, because the ButtonImage wants to fill the parent.
How can I set to fullscreen for every type of display?

Comment: can you added the code with question right its unclear what exactly you are asking . There is no such thing as `ButtonImage`

Comment: ImageButton I meant sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams pp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        b.setLayoutParams(pp);
```

This will set the match parent params to the button b. Change it as needed to match your code. Note that if you have Linear or Relative or anything else, simply change

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
```

To

```
YourLayout.LayoutParams
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that:

```
yourButton.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT););
```